# Proper way to combine model functions

Tags: php, opencart

Im working with Opencart and I have I have these functions in my model file that are essentially the same thing. Is there a better way of doing this? It seems like a waste to keep repeating lines of code, but Im not sure what the proper way of handling this is.  Can I combine these statements somehow? Is that a proper way of doing this? My PHP skills are not quite there and some advice here would be appreciated. Here are the functions

```
    public function getSum() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ");           
           return $query->row; 
    }
        public function lastThirty() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)" );            
           return $query->row; 
    }
 public function lastYearNow() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ");           
           return $query->row; //will be giving this time last year, not figured out yet.
    }
        public function lastYearTotal() {
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)" );            
           return $query->row; //will be total for last last year, not figured out yet.
    }
```

Comment: I would not do this.  These are small methods - it's not like there's a ton of code being copied.  You might need to tweak them in the future (say getSum() should exclude certain transactions for example), and it will be a pain if you have combined them.

Comment: Cool thank you! I always seem to take the long way, and sometimes there's a shortcut that I don't know about.

Comment: If there was *logic* in those functions, I'd say, sure, [dry it up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), but these are just trivial functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a single function instead of four and use a parameter for the dynamic value i.e. month. So your method will look something like this :

```
public function getSum($month = 12) {
  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL " . $month . " MONTH) ");           
  return $query->row; 
}
```

And while calling to this method you can pass result you want for the number of month or else it will show the result for 12 Month. Hope this will help you.

Note : It is advisable to keep all these methods as these contain small amount of code and in feature you might need different method to do different operation.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the duplicate code into a method and only give number of months (if this is the only difference) as an argument. I would however keep all other methods for sake of verbosity.